# Structures and class in c++

Tags: c++, oop

I am new to c++ and am told to understand a c++ code related to my project. I'm not sure what this means. car is a class car_CallBack is defined in some top level directory(as i'm told). I'm not clear about the first 3 lines of code. I believe the 4th line of code to be a constructor. Please provide me some insight as to what the snippet may mean...

```
struct model_ares : car,
public car_CallBack,
module_if::model_ares
{
  model_ares(const char *model_name);
  void init();
  void start_test();
```

Comment: If you are new to C++, then your first priority should be to read a good book. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/4891093

Answer (score 3):

What is means is that `model_ares` is a type that inherits publicly from `car`, `car_CallBack` and `module_if::model_ares`, and has a public converting constructor and two other public member functions.

In C++, `class` and `struct` are essentially the same. Default inheritance and members are `public` for `struct` and `private` for `class`. That is the only difference. You can express exactly the same types using either.

Your code is completely equivalent to

```
class model_ares : public car, 
                   public car_CallBack, 
                   public module_if::model_ares
{
 public:
  model_ares(const char *model_name);
  void init();
  void start_test();
};
```

Comment: do you mean that the two model_ares in "model_ares" and "module_if::model_ares" are different?? Also what do you mean by public converting constructor here ie whose private variables are being made public?

Comment: @RoyOneMillion yes, they should be different types. The public converting constructor is `model_ares(const char *model_name);`.

Comment: If it inherits from 3 sources( car, car_CallBack and module_if::model_ares), what may be the reason why access modifier(public) required only before car_CallBack?

Comment: @RoyOneMillion it is not required. As I explained in my answer, inheritance is `public` by default in `struct`. Whoever wrote `public` there was probably just doing it for fun.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, struct is same as class. Only one difference is that default visibilityof struct members is public, and private for classes.

Comment: i understand that, but what does the kind of combination of class and struct mean here?

Comment: thank you @dmitry, but can you provide a more c++ related link ??

Comment: Just type `Multiple inheritance C++` in google and get a lot of related links.